# Angular Controller organization and ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a simple list display, but I am having some concerns about Controllers organization.

In my application, I have 2 states, `items` and `state2`. In `items`, I want to display a list of Items, and "something else" in `state2`.

But I also have a `+` button at the top of my application that can add an item to my list. And I want that button to be displayed in both states. Here is an illustration:

[image: Illustration of the problem]

Now, I would like to put my `items` related functions, in a specific controller `ItemsCtrl`. So this would be my routes:

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/items");
  $stateProvider
    .state('items', {
      url: "/items",
      templateUrl: "partials/items.html",
      controller: "ItemsCtrl"
    })
    .state('state2', {
      url: "/state2",
      templateUrl: "partials/state2.html",
      controller: "State2Ctrl"
    });
});
```

And this would be my `ItemsCtrl`:

```
myApp.controller('ItemsCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.items = ["One",'Two'];
})
```

And now, I make a new `MainCtrl` to handle the `+` button that should be present on any page:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.promptItem = function(){
    var result = prompt('Add Item', 'New Item', ['ok'], 'Zero');
    $scope.items.push(result.input1); //This line doesn't work
  }
})
```

What is the best organization for this kind of interface? Do I really need to put my `$scope.items` in my `MainCtrl`?

I'd rather not, and the best thing I think would even be to put the `promptItem` function in `ItemsCtrl`, what do you think?

Thanks a lot for your answers, I am completely new to this world :)

EDIT: Here is my HTML structure, my `+` button is in the root file:

```
<button ng-click="promptProduct()">Add Item</button>
<a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a>
<a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a>
<div ui-view></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a great place to leverage an Angular service. The problem from what I understand is that you are struggling to share state between different parts of your application. I would recommend creating, e.g. a ListService, as such:

```
myApp.service('ListService', ListService);

function ListService () {
  this.list = ['One', 'Two'];
}
ListService.prototype = {
  addItemToList: function (newThing) {
    var item = // some initialization of an item from the passed value
    this.list.push(item);
  }
};
```

You can then inject `ListService` anywhere you need access to the data itself. Both the list view and the `state2` need it -- the former to actually render the list, and the latter to modify its contents. The method I described above lets you separate the data (the list itself) from the presentation / UI interaction.

[edit]

Likewise, if you want a button that lets you add a new item in both of your views, you could create a directive that receives `ListService` and prompts the user with a modal when clicked.

Comment: Thanks for showing me services, I didn't know that, but I am not sure this is adapted, because this would suit if my `+` button was both inside the first view and the second view. In my case, the button is in the root file, outside the `ui-view`. I edited the question with the HTML `index.html` file. Tell me if I am wrong

Comment: Ah, I see. You could also inject ListService into your MainCtrl, and there would not be a problem. This ends up not being terribly different from your initial solution, in the end.

Comment: Yes, I think that this is what I am going to do, put my `$scope.items` in `MainCtrl`, I guess if I need a `+` on top of my application that this is enough to consider the `items` as part of the "Main Data", thanks for the advices!

Comment: @cmw I would still prefer a service and a directive if the plus button is out of `ui-view`.